# Clicar no link e carregar novo Vídeo

Tags: javascript, html

estou precisando de ajuda com o seguinte problema:

Tenho monitoramento de câmeras e quero disponibiliza-las para alguns usuários, mas quero que eles visualizem apenas uma por vez para não pesar demais o link, então comecei a fazer o código abaixo, mas não consigo fazer outra câmera tomar o lugar da que esta sendo reproduzida no momento que clico no botão.

Como as câmeras são Streaming, a unica tag que funcionou nos meus testes para reproduzir o vídeo foi a embed.

Obrigado.

Código:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">            
            function mudacamera(cam) {

                if (cam == 1) {
                    document.getElementById("player").href = "rtsp://192.168.40.20:554/user=admin&password=171912&channel=1&stream=0.sdp";
                    alert("Camera selecionada: " + cam);
                } // if 1

                if (cam == 2) {
                    document.getElementById("player").target = "rtsp://192.168.40.20:554/user=admin&password=171912&channel=2&stream=0.sdp";
                    alert("Camera selecionada: " + cam);
                } //if 2

                if (cam == 3) {
                    document.getElementById("player").target = "rtsp://192.168.40.20:554/user=admin&password=171912&channel=3&stream=0.sdp";
                    alert("Camera selecionada: " + cam);
                } // if 3

                if (cam == 4) {
                    document.getElementById("player").target = "rtsp://192.168.40.20:554/user=admin&password=171912&channel=4&stream=0.sdp";
                    alert("Camera selecionada: " + cam);
                } // if 4
            }            
        </script>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="mudacamera(1)">Cam1</a>
        <a href="javascript:mudacamera(2)">Cam2</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="mudacamera(3)">Cam3</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="mudacamera(4)">Cam4</a><br/>

        <h1>Video</h1>

        <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" id="player" name="video1" autoplay="yes" loop="yes" width="400" height="300"
            target="rtsp://192.168.40.20:554/user=admin&password=171912&channel=1&stream=0.sdp" />    

    </body>
</html>
```